# Finding, removing, and replacing a words in a string (manually)

Tags: java

I am trying to create a meathod in Java that finds a word (paramter) inside a phrase (parameter) and replace it with another word (parameter). The challenge is to not use any special functions that does the work for me. I would like to know how to find and replace with Java's built in functions alone (no importing modules). I also cannot use the replace command and would like to change the code with substrings. The code that I currently have is:

```
  public static String searchAndReplace(String phrase, String searchWord, String replaceWord){
    String newPhrase = "";
    int findIndex = phrase.indexOf(searchWord);

    while (findIndex >=0){
      newPhrase = phrase.substring(0,findIndex)+phrase.substring(findIndex + searchWord.length());

      findIndex = phrase.indexOf(replaceWord);
    }
    return newPhrase;
  }
```

The current code doesn't work as it is supposed to.

Comment: @Zephyr correction - no regex here, should be `String.replace()`

Comment: I need to fine another way, manipulating strings, without the replace command.

Comment: then you should update your question to make it more clear.. *find and replace with Java's built in functions alone* sounds contradictory to the previous statement

Comment: If you can't use replace method then, make 2 char[] namely src and dest. Now initialize src with the input string, and copy each character to dest array - provided that you have already checked if the word you are entering is valid! (for this you can use intelligent algorithms, and they are many)

Comment: You need to be much more descriptive in your requirements and what you actually need. `replace()` is a core Java method that does not require any additional imports. If you are looking to manually process the String yourself for some reason, please make that clearer in your question.

Comment: @Zephyr Yes. I am sorry that I did not make it clear enough. I will change my question now.

Comment: @Ketan I have only studies Java for a short while. I am unsure on what you have just said as it is too complicated by my understandings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Just added `replaceWord` in the string concatenation and removed the `newPhrase` variable. The final code looks like this:-

```
public static String searchAndReplace(String phrase, String searchWord, String replaceWord) {
    int findIndex = phrase.indexOf(searchWord);

    while (findIndex >= 0) {
        phrase = phrase.substring(0, findIndex) + replaceWord + phrase.substring(findIndex + searchWord.length());

        findIndex = phrase.indexOf(searchWord);
    }
    return phrase;
}
```

**Edit**

The problem with your `newPhrase` was at a few places like:-

```
findIndex = phrase.indexOf(replaceWord); //inside while loop
```

You changed your `newPhrase` but you were still checking for the word in the original `phrase`. Also, you were looking for `replaceWord` instead of `searchWord`.

Comment: Yes. It works. I understand why you put in replace word. However, why did you remove newPhrase (I tested my code with newPhrase and it doesn't work but I want to know the reason why)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible way of doing it. Please see the comments in the code below:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String search = "dog";
        String replace = "cat";

        String originalPhrase = "I have a dog.";

        System.out.println(replaceWord(originalPhrase, search, replace));
    }

    private static String replaceWord(String originalPhrase, String searchWord, String replaceWord) {

        // Assuming you cannot use a StringBuilder...
        String finalPhrase = "";

        // First, determine if the searchWord even exists in the originalPhrase
        if (originalPhrase.contains(searchWord)) {

            // Catch character indexes for the start and end of the searchWord within our originalPhrase
            int start = originalPhrase.indexOf(searchWord);
            int end = start + searchWord.length();

            // Add the beginning of the originalPhrase (up to the searchWord) to our finalPhrase
            finalPhrase += originalPhrase.substring(0, start);

            // Add our replaceWord
            finalPhrase += replaceWord;

            // Gather the rest of the phrase (after the searchWord)
            finalPhrase += originalPhrase.substring(end);

            // Return our completed phrase
            return finalPhrase;

        } else {

            // If the search word doesn't exist, return the original phrase
            return originalPhrase;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to find another way; without the replace command.

Comment: You should probably add that to your question, then. `replace()` is a core Java method.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a different method. It's very similar to what you came up with, but I've spread it out a bit to provide comments as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to discover and develop the algorithm yourself, you should do it traditionally with pen and paper.

- Draw the strings as sequences of boxes, have some coins or pins as pointer variables.
- Define what the basic allowed operations are. For example "compare two characters", "add one character to the end of a string", "compare two regions of a string".
- Write down your algorithm in everyday words.
- Follow the algorithm manually.
- Think of useful test cases, like

  - The replaceWord appears at the beginning
  - The replaceWord appears in the middle
  - The replaceWord appears at the end
  - The replaceWord doesn't appear at all
  - The replaceWord appears twice in a row
  - "a" is replaced with "aaa"

A completely different approach is to write `"source".replace("a", "aaa")` in your Java IDE and step through all the single steps using a debugger. [Since Java 9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8058779), String.replace is implemented as exactly the basic character operations that you are looking for. The green part of [this code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/rev/db30d5179fe7) also contains some test cases from very experienced developers.

Before doing the second approach, you should have done the first approach and understood it completely. Only then will you be able to step through the code and compare the steps that actually happen with the steps you expect to happen.